# Export Captured Movie Only plays in Landscape Mode, and is Rotated

Tags: iphone

Before I post a lot of code here is the scenario:

1. Using code based on AVEditDemo from WWDC, I capture a movie using the standard control in portrait.
2. I post process the video using code identical to that in AVEditDemo which uses Core Animation.

When I play the resultant video using the Camera App, it is rotated 90 degrees and is not longer "portrait" (it is now in landscape) and squashed. (The aspect ratio seems to have been swapped, width -> height & height -> width.

Have spent many hours on this and am at a loss.

The desired result is a movie identical to the captured original. (With an animated overlay eventually).

To see this in action just download and run the AVEditDemo from Apple, turn Title "ON" and export the movie.

Comment: Hello, I have tried this exact code myself and it doesn't work.  Does anyone have a solution? I am desperate to find out the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the short answer is this:

When processing the original video, you want to retrieve the 'preferredTransform':

```
AVAssetTrack *sourceVideo = [[sourceAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo]lastObject];
CGAffineTransform *preferredTransform = [sourceVideo preferredTransform];
```

and then when writing the final video you will do something similar to this:

```
AVMutableComposition *composition = [AVMutableComposition composition];

AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionVideoTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo 
     preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
AVMutableCompositionTrack *compositionAudioTrack = [composition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio 
     preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[compositionVideoTrack setPreferredTransform:preferredTransform];
```